# Why does this code keep giving this error? Syntax error: Bad for loop variable

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, syntax

This is copied from The C Programming Language By Ritchie. I've tried to make some modifications but it always gets stuck on the for loop (line 7)

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{

    int fahr;

    for(fahr = 0; fahr <= 300; fahr = fahr + 20)
    {
        printf("%3d %6.1f\n", fahr, (5.0/9.0)*(fahr-32));

    }

}
```

error: ./farn.c: 8: ./farn.c: Syntax error: Bad for loop variable

Comment: Works fine for me: http://ideone.com/ucPtev Do you maybe have a stray character in your file somewhere? Try use *hexdump* or *less* to investigate.

Comment: Works for me.  How are you compiling it?

Comment: Are you sure you are editing the same file you are compiling?

Comment: I'd be equally concerned about the ambiguous nature of your `main()` return, which is not in line with the standard. What compiler is this being built with anyway? (and I'm curious if you receive the same erro with `fahr += 20` for your final expression stmt.)

Comment: Please post the exact command you are using to compile this. And anything else you do before you get that message.

Answer (score 4):

I reproduced your problem. On Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is symbolically linked to `dash`.

```
$ dash ./farn.c
./farn.c: 8: Syntax error: Bad for loop variable
```

It is very rare for a C program to be correctly interpreted by a Bourne shell interpreter (or one of its derivatives).

Compile the program with a C compiler, and run the executable (alternatively, use a C language interpreter if you can find one). On Ubuntu, you can use `gcc`:

```
$ gcc -W -Wall -Werror -pedantic -std=c99 farn.c -o farn
$ ./farn
```

Since the K&R book predates C.99, the above compilation command will generate an error:

```
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
farn.c:4: warning: return type defaults to 'int'
```

To fix this, you can simply update the declaration of `main()` with an explicit `int` return type. In C.99, encountering the `}` at the end of `main()` implicitly returns `0`, so adding `int` is sufficient.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int fahr;

    for(fahr = 0; fahr <= 300; fahr = fahr + 20)
    {
        printf("%3d %6.1f\n", fahr, (5.0/9.0)*(fahr-32));

    }

}
```

Comment: After googling (in quotes) "Bad for loop variable", I had just reached the same conclusion - "this was being run through a shell, not a compiler". You beat me by about a minute...

Comment: I would probably want to add - "compile the program with the following line: `gcc farn.c -o farn`, then run it with `./farn`.

Comment: Nice catch to reproduce using dash.

Answer (score 0):

Your code compiles correctly. This is the proof : http://codepad.org/hryZ2dEm

I have also added the return type and the return instruction in the main function to make your code conform to the standard. Try to use the small changes I have inserted.

Let me know if you still have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the fact that you're defining main() in a very lazy way and the lack of a return statement, I don't see anything wrong at all with the code above. After fixing those 2 issues, it compiled and ran just fine with the following options:

```
gcc temperature.c -g -Wall -Werror -pedantic -o temperature
```

As an aside, the entry-point to main should be either of:

```
int main(void) // You *can* leave void out here, but it's best to be explicit
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) // 2nd arg could also be char** argv
```

And you should always return an integer value from main, usually a return of 0 indicates the program ran successfully.

Comment: He was following the K & R book exactly, I am sure.

Comment: I'm sure he is, it seems to be a problem with his environment rather than his code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for the advice everyone. I solved my problem by using GCC like a boss.

```
gcc farn.c -o farn
```

then

```
./farn
```

works great. :-)